# Sign Certificate with custom CA on runtime

Tags: openssl

Hallo, what specific functions do i have to use to generate certificate and programmaticaly sign it with my custom CA. I cant find anything useful in the openssl documentation. Thx for answer

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to look at the source of the respective command line tools, e.g. the [ca](http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/apps/ca.c&v=1.174) subcommand. You'll find fragments of code that you can glue together to your needs.

Comment: arent there any api functions? do i have to reasearch this file?

Comment: Sure there are API functions. But you need plenty of them, so it's best to look at the code to find out what they are and how they fit together.